# Creating a list with nested lists

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc

I have made algorithms to create a list with nested lists in order to then show them in a tree view. From what users told me, my view method is fine, but the way I create the final list is probably not doing so well since it takes 9 seconds for my page to load on a test web deploy environment.

This is what my viewmodel looks like:

```
public class CategoryModel
{
    public long idCategory { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string path{ get; set; }
    public int idParentCategory { get; set; }
    public int order { get; set; }
    public int depth { get; set; }
    // List of child categories that can go deeper.
    // In a way childCategories are branches
    public List<CategoryModel> childCategories { get; set; }
    public int selected { get; set; }
}
```

So first, I create a list with all categories:

```
 public List<CategoryModel> GetSuperUserCategories()
 {
    // I use this model for having a final model to pass to the view
    List<CategoryModel> catModel = new List<CategoryModel>();
    // Here I retrieve the categories in Entity Framework form, but I add it to CategoryModel
    // later on so it can be used as a ViewModel, hence avoiding Entities to be
    // in my view
    List<Web_Categories> categories = menuRepo.GetAllCategories();
    if (categories == null || categories.Count == 0)
        return null;
    else
    {   // Add all categories to the list here
        foreach(var cat in categories)
        {
            //You can see model properties here
            catModel.Add(new CategoryModel
            {
                idCategory = cat.IDCategorie,
                name = cat.Nom,
                path = cat.CheminPhysique,
                idParentCategory = cat.IDCategorieMere,
                depth = 0,
                order = cat.Ordre,
                childCategories = new List<CategoryModel>()
            });
        }
        return catModel;
    }
}
```

Then I have a method to determine the nested lists, which categories has child categories and inside these children categories I do the same:

```
public List<CategoryModel> getDocumentsChildren(List<CategoryModel> categories)
{
    int depth=0;
    try
    {
        long i;
        //Loop on categories
        foreach (var cat in categories)
        {
            i = cat.idCategory;
            if (cat.idParentCategory == 0) {
                cat.depth = 0; //Determine depth for display
                continue;
        }
            //We loop twice to find nested categories
            //Is idParentCategory of our current loop equal to our first loop idCategory?
            foreach (var nextCat in categories)
            {
                if (nextCat.idParentCategory == cat.idCategory && nextCat.idCategory != cat.idCategory)
                {
                    nextCat.depth = cat.depth + 1;
                    cat.childCategories.Add(nextCat);
                }
            }            
        }
        //Once the children elements have been determined, We can remove top
        //nodes so that they don't show and are only nested 
        foreach (var cat in categories.ToList())
        {
            if (cat.idParentCategory != 1)
                categories.Remove(cat);
        }
        return categories;
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Une erreur s'est produite : " + e.ToString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Finally I sort all the lists with recursive calls:

```
public List<CategoryModel> SortCategoryModel(List<CategoryModel> model)
{
    foreach(var m in model)
    {
        if (m.childCategories != null)
        {
            m.childCategories = m.childCategories.OrderBy(c=>c.name).ToList();
            //recurse on childCategories
            m.childCategories = SortCategoryModel(m.childCategories);
        }
    }
    return model;
}
```

Note that I have a total of 119 categories. I use these methods for all the treeview generations, also for creating a dynamic menu which takes about 15 seconds to load in test deploy environment. I believe the `SortCategoryModel` method to be the issue but I'm not sure how to improve it?

I also search `childDocuments`, but I removed it here because it does not change much

After measuring the time it takes to make these three methods combined, I find 5.4357 milliseconds. It seems weird my page turns to 15 seconds loading. I'll mention my virtual machine is always around 90% RAM usage. Could this be an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have written about 10 times as much code as needed to create your collection of `CategoryModel` You can greatly simplify this by using linq queries, and gain some performance as well.

I would first suggest you sort on the database, rather than calling a method that returns a in-memory collection of `Web_Categories` and running multiple loops and recursive methods. Then you can use `.Lookup()` to group your items

```
// Sort and group the categories
var groups = _context.Web_Categories
    .OrderBy(x => x.idParentCategory).ThenBy(x => x.name)
    .ToLookup(x => x.idParentCategory, x => new CategoryModel
    {
        idCategory = x.idCategory,
        name = x.name,
        ....
    });
```

Then use a single loop to assign the child categories

```
// Assign children
foreach (var item in groups.SelectMany(x => x))
{
    item.childCategories = groups[item.idCategory].ToList();
}
```

and finally return the top level parents

```
List<CategoryVM> result = groups[null].ToList();
```

Its not clear why your view model has properties such as `int idParentCategory` and `int order` and `int depth`, and based on you (now closed) [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/175369/show-a-treeview-of-nested-lists-with-radio-buttons) they are not necessary. In addition, I suggest your `idParentCategory` property in the data model/database table be nullable, so that a value of `null` (rather than a value of `0`) denotes a top level category.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. idParentCategory refers to the parent category of a category. It is organized this way in my table Web_Categories, this is how you know which elements are child elements. In the code you proposed, how do we know it's a child element (assign children part)? As for depth, I used it for creating my menu and adding css to elements that need a bigger margin, should've removed it here since indeed it is not relevant. Order I have left because it is in the table but I found no use for it (it's more of a specification, I have to talk to my boss about this).

Comment: Also, isn't in the same 'assign children' part : `item.Categories` should be `item.childCategories`? I understand more now for the ambiguity of `idParentCategory`, I do it because I create the model, and then to know children I use it, but I guess with a method more like yours, I won't necessarily need it. It all depends if I determine children directly on DB access or after creating the model. If I determine the children using the model, then I need this property to know which elements are child.

Comment: Yes, I understand what the `idParentCategory` is for. What I'm saying is that it should be a nullable field. If the `Web_Categories` is a top level category, its value should be `null` (not `0`)

Comment: And you do not need the `depth` property, that can simply be done using css (I will show how to do that later)

Comment: Yes, it should be `item.childCategories` (will edit in a moment)

Comment: You really need to start following normal naming conventions :)

Comment: Yeah I know, I kinda rushed into this project without the proper background. thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65883/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-flexabust-bergson).

Answer (score 2):

What is sure it's that you have a bottleneck so my approach to find out would be to measure every method execution by using a stopwatch...

Also, after a second sight, I see too many for each loops, you might rethink a bit your algorithm to minimize so many loops and also try linq to, for instance, order the results or use where clauses.